# Trying to Add a value as CSV in Linq lambda statement with groupby

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to get a list of vouchers in my ouput as CSV ,     e.g.   1,2,3,4

Can't seem to figure it out  `Vouchers =  VoucherId ,  VoucherID`   is what i want

```
var paymentGroups = new List<PaymentGroups>();

paymentGroups = paymentVouchers
.GroupBy(x => new { x.PayFromBankAccountId, x.PaymentType}) 
.Select(x => new PaymentGroups
{
    PayFromBankAccountId = x.Key.PayFromBankAccountId,
    PaymentType = x.Key.PaymentType,
    TotalAmounts = x.Sum(z => z.TotalPaymentAmount), 
    TotalCount = x.Count(),
    //Group = x.Count()
    //Vouchers = x.All(y => y.VoucherId != null)
    //Vouchers = string.Join(y => y.
    //Vouchers = x.Sum(y => y.VoucherId.ToString())
    Vouchers =  VoucherId ,  VoucherID 
}).ToList();


var paymentVouchers = new List<PaymentVouchers>()
{

    new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "ABC", PaymentType = 5, TotalPaymentAmount = 100, VoucherId = "1" },
    new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "ABC", PaymentType = 5, TotalPaymentAmount = 200, VoucherId = "2" },
    new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "ABC", PaymentType = 5, TotalPaymentAmount = 300, VoucherId = "3" },
    new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "ABC", PaymentType = 6, TotalPaymentAmount = 100, VoucherId = "4" },
    new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "ABC", PaymentType = 6, TotalPaymentAmount = 200, VoucherId = "5" },
    new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "ABC", PaymentType = 6, TotalPaymentAmount = 300, VoucherId = "6" },
    new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "DEF", PaymentType = 5, TotalPaymentAmount = 100, VoucherId = "7" },
    new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "DEF", PaymentType = 5, TotalPaymentAmount = 200, VoucherId = "8" },
    new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "DEF", PaymentType = 6, TotalPaymentAmount = 100, VoucherId = "9" },
    new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "DEF", PaymentType = 6, TotalPaymentAmount = 200, VoucherId = "10" },
};
```

Here are the classes with the properties

```
public class PaymentGroups
{
    public Int32 Group {get; set;}
    public string PayFromBankAccountId { get; set; }
    public int PaymentType { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAmounts { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    public string Vouchers {get; set;}
}

public class PaymentVouchers
{
    public string VoucherId {get; set;}
    public string PayFromBankAccountId { get; set; }
    public int PaymentType { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPaymentAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could select all *VoucherId* and concatenate them with [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0), like :

```
Vouchers = string.Join(",", x.Select(y => y.VoucherId ));
```

Comment: x.  is the red underline part in linqpad

Comment: Do you know how I can add an auto-incremented field?   so another column of say  Group = DistinctNumber

Comment: @JeremyMiller, you can add variable `int counter = 0;` and inside Select statemenent increment this variable like `Group = counter++;` other option to test : `.Select((i,x)=> new PaymentGroups {Group = i++; TotalCount = x.Count();}`